# Why Invalid regular expression flags in this mern project?

Tags: mern

```
router.post(/post/save, (req, res) => {
```

Can anyone help me to solve this javascript error in /post/save?

Comment: This question is already answered. But next time, adding the exact error message is recommended

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the route `/post/save` in inverted commas.

```js
router.post("/post/save", (req, res) => {}
```